# Rails get response time for a curl (JSON) request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, curl, response-time

In my app do I multiple request to an external server like this:

```
    req = Curl::Easy.new do |curl| 
        curl.url = "https://www.mysite.com"
        curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    end
    req.perform
```

It is possible to retrieve the response time (how long takes the request)?

A solution that I think is working is the following (pseudocode), but there is something more elegant?

```
    req = Curl::Easy.new do |curl| 
        curl.url = "https://www.mysite.com"
        curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    end

    timeBefore = Time.now
    req.perform
    timeAfter = Time.now
    responseTime = timeAfter - timeBefore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ruby's Benchmark module as follows:

```
time = Benchmark.realtime do
      req.perform
end
puts "Time elapsed #{time*1000} milliseconds"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know the existence of this module